# Change map key from values that are content in value of the same map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Having the next map:

```
{
  G1=[
    User(id=1005, name=Jack, age=45), 
    User(id=1006, name=Carl, age=23),
    User(id=1007, name=Thomas, age=20),
    User(id=1008, name=Peter, age=19),
    User(id=1009, name=John, age=47),
    User(id=1010, name=Adrian, age=21),
    User(id=1011, name=Mariah, age=18)
  ],
  G2=[
    User(id=1005, name=Alfred, age=23), 
    User(id=1006, name=Barack, age=22),
    User(id=1007, name=Lee, age=36),
    User(id=1008, name=Andrew, age=33),
    User(id=1009, name=Sophia, age=22),
    User(id=1010, name=Lauren, age=19),
    User(id=1011, name=Mathias, age=33)
  ]
}
```

How can I create this map:

```
{
  47=[
    User(id=1005, name=Jack, age=45), 
    User(id=1006, name=Carl, age=23),
    User(id=1007, name=Thomas, age=20),
    User(id=1008, name=Peter, age=19),
    User(id=1009, name=John, age=47),
    User(id=1010, name=Adrian, age=21),
    User(id=1011, name=Mariah, age=18)
  ],
  36=[
    User(id=1005, name=Alfred, age=23), 
    User(id=1006, name=Barack, age=22),
    User(id=1007, name=Lee, age=36),
    User(id=1008, name=Andrew, age=33),
    User(id=1009, name=Sophia, age=22),
    User(id=1010, name=Lauren, age=19),
    User(id=1011, name=Mathias, age=33)
  ]
}
```

Where the new key is the result of getting the max value of age attribute from User list.

In a map without the User list in the value this works:

```
Original map: {G1=[45,23,20,19,47,21,18], G2=[23,22,36,33,22,19,33]}

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> newMap = mapa.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> Collections.max(e.getValue()),
                        Map.Entry::getValue));

Result: {47=[45,23,20,19,47,21,18], 36=[23,22,36,33,22,19,33]}
```

But with the User list, I can get the object inside Collector.toMap.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

map from the `User` to their age and then get the maximum:

```
source.values()
      .stream()
      .collect(toMap(l -> l.stream()
                        .mapToInt(User::getAge)
                        .max().getAsInt(), Function.identity()));
```

or using `Collections.max`:

```
source.values()
     .stream()
     .collect(toMap(l -> Collections.max(l, 
          Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge)).getAge(), Function.identity()));
```